# Do we ever see a Federation Starfleet Space Station?

Tags: star-trek

Star Trek DS9 focuses on a space station rather than a starship - specifically the Deep Space 9 space station.

[image]

However, this is not a Federation space station - it is formally owned by the Bajorans.  In fact, it isn't even a Bajoran station - it was put there during the occupation of the Cardassians, and in fact is a Cardassian-built space station.

Do we, at any point in Star Trek canon, get to see what a Federation-constructed Space Station looks like?

Comment: It is a Bajoran station. It became a Bajoran station when the Cardassians abandoned it after the occupation.

Comment: -1 Since you have done absolute zero research before asking this. A simple Google search would yield a bunch of Federation space stations.

Comment: "it is formally owned by the Bajorans" — the Cardassians might disagree.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Yes, however sporadically**

This is a [decent list of Starfleet Space Stations](http://outrightgeekery.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/outright-geekerys-top-o-the-lot-united-federation-of-planets-space-stations/) we see through the series.  Here's a couple:

*There is [K-7](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-7), infamous for tribble infestations*

[image]

*The rather generic "[Spacedock](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spacedock_type)", which appears in TOS movies as well as in TNG, DIS and LD episodes*

[image]

*[Jupiter Station](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Jupiter_Station) from Enterprise*

[image]

*[Mckinley Station](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/McKinley_Station)*

[image]

*[Starbase 1](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_1) from the Abramsverse*

[image]

Comment: And unlike Federation starships, the stations do seem quite varied in design, even they still adhere to a kind of "dome" theme

Comment: Nicely done.  Seems like the first two are pretty similar, any reason for the third one being so different? (Obviously the fourth one is different because Abrams)

Comment: All just design shifts due to time and show production (in this case Voyager), I think - although in-universe you could argue McKinley is probably the most "dock" oriented design, it doesn't do much else it seems

Comment: Not to mention there are many other designs. There does not seem to be a particular reason or rational to their design structure and they are all far more massive than their starships. It seems the Federation COULD build more massive starships but they don't...

Comment: You're missing what I think is the most frequently-seen design, the "Spacedock" style space station which appeared in four of the Star Trek movies (III-VI) and also a bunch of times on Star Trek: The Next Generation-- http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spacedock_type

Comment: Good catch, added.  I think I had it and then accidentally edited it out for the Abramsverse one.

Comment: IIRC, McKinley Station was specifically for starship repair/retrofit/etc. so it seems the form followed function.

Comment: It's also worth noting that we actually see K-7 in an episode of DS9 as well.

Comment: @Thaddeus Building large spaceships is rather more complicated than building large space stations. A brilliant essay on the topic can be found here: http://stardestroyer.net/Empire/Science/Size.html (as chance has it, it does actually cover Star Trek among others). The site analyses Federation's capabilities in extreme depth, I can definitely recommend reading it all, unless you're "a rabbid trekkie" :D

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the ones posted by @joshbirk, there are other Federation space stations.

**[Star Base 375](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_375)** - This was the staging ground of the Federation counter attack against the Dominion following the withdrawal from Deep Space 9. This model Starbase appears to have also served as a basis for prison bases on a [couple](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_Federation_space_stations#Gaila.27s_prison_starbase) [occasions](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_Federation_space_stations#Eddington.27s_prison_starbase). [Starbase 173](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_173) and [Starbase 257](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_257) also are based on this model.

[image: Starbase 375]

**[Utopia Planitia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Utopia_Planitia_Fleet_Yards)** - A large Federation construction facility. Notably, the Galaxy, Intrepid and Defiant classes were designed, tested and constructed here. Additionally, within this cluster of stations, there are several different models (a McKinley station is noticeable, multiple dry docks and at least 3 'bubble' stations are are probably administration/defense (speculation on my part) )

[image: Utopia Planitia]

**[Star Base 74](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_74)** - This is based on the Spacedock model. It appears to serve the same purpose of star ship repair/maintenance, as the Enterprise-D docked here for computer upgrades. [Star Base 84](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_84) is also a Spacedock type star base.

[image: Star base 74]

**[Starbase 234](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_234)** - This is similar to the Mckinley Station type stations.

[image: Starbase 234]

Comment: Star Base 375 actually looks to be based on station Regula One from Wrath of Khan.

Comment: I only wish I could accept both of these answers.  Very through investigation and nice finds!

Comment: +1 for making me really sad (again) that NASA gave up.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to those shown in the other answers, there is also [Epsilon IX Station](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Epsilon_IX_station) from Star Trek: The Motion Picture:
[image: Epsilon IX Station]

and Starbase 6 from the TOS Remastered edition:
[image]

and the Regula I research lab from *The Wrath of Khan*:
[image: Regula I research lab]

which [it turns out is an upside-down re-use of a model built for *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Orbital_office_complex) as an orbital office complex:
[image]

which was also re-used for starbases in TNG and DS9 (e.g. Starbase 375 mentioned by Andy).